# UISearchBar in UIPopoverController not getting first responder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchcontroller, uipopover

When a user presses the search bar button, a popover appears with a search bar. I am loading the search results view from a nib that contains just a tableview. Now, I want the search bar to become selected when the popover appears however the search bar is not getting first responder. I have tried setting it in the `didPresentSearchController:` delegate method but that doesn't work either. Below is the code that I have tried.

```
- (IBAction)search:(id)sender {
    self.searchView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Popover" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.searchView];
    self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[@"BLARGH", @"WARGH"];
    self.searchController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex = 1;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;

    self.table.delegate = self;
    self.table.dataSource = self;
    self.table.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

    self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.searchView];

    [self.popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 88)];
    self.popover.delegate = self;

    [self.popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.searchButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    [self.searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [self.popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 600)];
    self.table.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 600);
    NSLog(@"Me pressed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it helping you 
Use this Delegate and also check in .xib or storyboard you have connected delegate of search bar or not

```
      - (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar 
     {
         [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
     }
```

Comment: The question is about how to get searchBar to become first responder. Resigning the searchBar is not what I am asking. Also as I have stated, `UITableView` is the only thing in my .xib